# Gruff is not working well. What to do?

Tags: ruby, charts, imagemagick, rmagick, gruff

I`m facing a problem with Gruff and Rails.
Examples on the [site](http://nubyonrails.com/pages/gruff) fail with:

```
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
from /home/prikha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rubymine/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:1066:in `label'
from /home/prikha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rubymine/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:590:in `setup_graph_measurements'
from /home/prikha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rubymine/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:532:in `setup_drawing'
from /home/prikha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rubymine/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:508:in `draw'
from /home/prikha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rubymine/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/line.rb:53:in `draw'
from /home/prikha/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rubymine/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:487:in `write'
from (irb):8
from /home/prikha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The way i solve it is the following:
ZeroDivisionError appears in 1066 line of gruff/base.rb
Let's look at this file closer

```
label = if (@spread.to_f % @marker_count.to_f == 0) || !@y_axis_increment.nil?
```

So, ZeroDivisionError was caused by the fact that @marker_count property was equal to zero. I know, it's not the best solution, but i've added an explicit assignment 
`@marker_count = <non-zero value>` before drawing graph.
So, now example from site looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'gruff'

g = Gruff::Line.new
g.title = "My Graph" 

g.data("Apples", [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3])
g.data("Oranges", [4, 8, 7, 9, 8, 9])
g.data("Watermelon", [2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 8])
g.data("Peaches", [9, 9, 10, 8, 7, 9])
g.marker_count = 4 #explicitly assign value to @marker_count
g.labels = {0 => '2003', 2 => '2004', 4 => '2005'}

g.write('my_fruity_graph.png')
```

It works fine for me. I know that it's not the general solution for the problem, but this hack can help you to deal with that library up until this error will be fixed by developers.

**ADD**
@market_count is a count of markers on vertical axis. So you can play with this property to prettify your graph.

Comment: Thats cool, it occured that piechart works fine. Hope someday somepone will fix this bug, but graphic libraries for ruby seems to be a dead space.

Comment: You can try to fix it by yourself, if you have enough time. Bug code is [here](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff/blob/master/lib/gruff/base.rb#L1069).

Comment: Pull request merged for a quick walkaround https://github.com/topfunky/gruff/pull/22